# Turn global array to local array and pass between functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, global, local

I am very very new to vanilla JS and I am currently working on an assignment that allows us freedom to create whatever kind of website we want on the basis that we break all of the code down into functions and that we do not use global variables.

I have almost completed a very basic address book that takes a name and phone number as input, stores the values into an array and returns the list of contacts when the 'view all contacts' button is pressed. My only dilemma is that the array is a global variable and I am not sure how to get this to work other wise.

### Update

I have added the entire code here. I am working in Brackets.

````
function init(){
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener("click", addContact)
document.getElementById("listButton").addEventListener("click", listContacts)
}

var contactList = [];


function getAttribute(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;   
}

function verifyNumber(number){
    var regExp = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var phone = number.match(regExp);
  if (phone) {
    outPut("alert","");
    return true;
  }else{
  outPut("alert","invalid phone number");
  return false;
}
}

function outPut(id,message){
    var messageBox = document.getElementById(id);
    messageBox.innerText = message;
    
}

function contact(name, number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    return ("Name: " + this.name +  "Number: "  + this.number);
    }



function addContact(){
    var name = getAttribute("name");
    var number = getAttribute("number");
    if(verifyNumber(number)){
     var newContact = new contact(name,number);
     contactList.push(newContact);
     alert("Contact Successfuly Added!");
    }
    

}


function listContacts(){
    contactList.forEach(element => console.log(element));
      contactList.forEach(Object => {var newElement = document.createElement('h1');
        newElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(Object);
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
                                    });
   
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) You could potentially use some kind of store to manage the data. Redux is an example. The answer is (as usual) "it depends". It would be best if you post some code that you have written already (are you using some kind of framework or just vanilla JS?) that we could see and maybe propose some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an object instead? like key: value pairs, and could you share a snippet of your code with us so we can help you better, thanks